# Pandas replace works in one line, but not in another

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to clean some data (Python 3.7.3) and was able to replace NaN values with empty strings using

```
def g(x):
    return pd.Series(x.replace(np.nan, ""))
df = df.apply(g)
```

and get the desired output:

```
1    2      3            4
qt>  qml>   tableview>
```

etc, but then I tried to do something similar to replace the ">" with an empty string

```
def h(x):
   return pd.Series(x.replace(">", ""))
df = df.apply(h)
```

but the dataframe doesn't change and I still have the ">" at the end of each word. No errors are thrown at me, so I'm at a loss. Thanks in advance for any answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `h` function with:

```py
def h(x):
   return pd.Series(x.str.replace(">", ""))
df = df.apply(h)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def h(x):
      return x.replace(">", "",regex=True)
df = df.apply(h)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
def g(x):
    return pd.Series(x.replace(">", "",regex=True))
df = df.apply(g)
```

This should work.